# 'he swims very well' or 'he to swim very well'?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

When do you use the verb which follows a personal pronoun with "to" and when without to?
Examples:

a. Do you have to read all the time?
b. He swims very well.
c. You know how to ride a bike, don´t you?

Comment: Your examples are all correct English, none of them have a verb with "to" following the pronoun.  "you (do) have"  "He swims"  "You know".

Comment: If you have two verbs together like "have" and "read", or "know" and "ride", then you normally need some way of linking them, such as a preposition. This is very basic English, so I'm not sure how you would be taught it.

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 0):

These examples all don't depend on the preceding verb following a personal pronoun.

In example a, [have to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20to) is a standard prepositional verb meaning 'are required to', 'must'.

In example b, you're right, 'swims' doesn't need a 'to' (unless you're swimming *to* a certain point in the swimming pool/lake/sea).

In example c, 'to' combines with the preceding 'how', not with the verb 'know'.